# What are the differences between -m, -s and -X arguments passed to git rebase?

Tags: git, git-rebase

Could you explain in plain English please what are the differences (or how do they work) between `-m`, `-s` and `-X` arguments that you should pass to `git rebase`?

Comment: Use this documentation (very detailed) http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These arguments don't do different things but rather modify how the rebase will apply the changes.

http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-rebase

```
-m, --merge

Use merging strategies to rebase. When the recursive (default) merge strategy is used, this allows rebase to be aware of renames on the upstream side.
Note that a rebase merge works by replaying each commit from the working branch on top of the <upstream> branch. Because of this, when a merge conflict happens, the side reported as ours is the so-far rebased series, starting with <upstream>, and theirs is the working branch. In other words, the sides are swapped.
```

In other words, rather than just applying the changes with each commit perform merge the changes into the branch.  For example, if a file was renamed, git will make your changes to that file rather than creating a new one.

The other arguments modify how the merge is performed:

```
-s <strategy>, --strategy=<strategy>

Use the given merge strategy. If there is no -s option git merge-recursive is used instead. This implies --merge.
Because git rebase replays each commit from the working branch on top of the <upstream> branch using the given strategy, using the ours strategy simply discards all patches from the <branch>, which makes little sense.
```

Git has multiple ways for determine which changes to use when merging changes.  This option specifies which one to use.  The default is `recursive`, but there are others that may be appropriate depending on the situation.

-X specifies any additional options to be passed to the merge strategy to be used.  For example `recursive` has three options that can be used: `ours`, `theirs`, and `subtree`.  You would use -X to specify which one that you want.